# Spring Configuration Query

Tags: spring

I have one spring configuration file with entry like below...

```
<bean id="beanId" class="a.b.c.d.MyBean">
        <property name="firstProperty" value="report_{date}.xls"/>
</bean>
```

Somewhere in my java code, I am fetching this bean and then its property "firstProperty" later.

I am little curious, when I get the value of property "firstProperty" I get report_.xls i.e report_20130307.xls

I have searched all my code including bundles, xmls but not clear that where we are setting {date} with todays timestamp.

Do you have any clue where we can do this?

Thanks

Jai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its quite simple guys...as we know setter are called for each property. So same in my case, 
In bean we are setting variable "firstProperty" + today timestamp like below.

```
public void setfirstProperty(String firstProperty) {
    this.firstProperty = firstProperty + <methodToReplaceDateStringWithTimeStamp>;
}
```

Thanks

Jai

Answer (score 0):

It is the property-placeholder mechanism.

Read more on http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-context-pphc.

Comment: No, this is not property-placeholder mechanism, I think. That I know very well, where bean property are set from the bundles key-value pair data. Because If you notice in my case, {date} is not static value holder. Its getting changed after every run.

Comment: Correct, if it was the property placeholder the placeholder would have to start with $. I.e. ${date} instead of {date}. Can you elaborate what you mean by "changed after every run" ?

Comment: It means, If I run my application again-and-again. Every time the value of "date" will be changed.

As such, I got the solution. Replied too.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases, the values to property are set from properties file using expression language. Like

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="a.b.c.d.DataSource">
    <property name="databaseUrl" value="{db.url}"/>
</bean>
```

Or if the property is a ref to another bean, e.g. Object B is member variable of Object A.

```
<bean id="refA" class="a.b.c.d.A">
    <property name="b" ref="refB"/>
</bean>

<bean id="refB" class="a.b.c.d.B">
</bean>
```